# RESTEasy cannot take in @PathParam typed Long

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, path-parameter

I have seen in tutorial (Jersey) that there is possibility to pass in JAX-RS **@PathParam** of type **Long**.

But when I have tried to do this with RESTEasy I'm getting error:

```
 21:50:32,353 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-15) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: long of content type: */*
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:73)
```

I tested it with Integer, but it also don't work...

```
22:14:45,590 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-18) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class java.lang.Integer of content type: */*
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
```

Moreover I am trying to take this ID value as String and then convert it to Long using **Long.valueOf(String s)** or **Long.parseLong(String s)** and in both cases I am getting error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at pl.salonea.jaxrs.UserAccountResource.getUserAccount(UserAccountResource.java:41)
```

It's the code of my web service resource method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{userId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public UserAccount getUserAccount(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {

    return userAccountFacade.find(Long.parseLong(userId));
}
```

**SOLVED**

I have bad import not **import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;**, but something from web sockets PathParam... I just relay on IntelliJ automatic imports and haven't seen that it was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the wrong import - fixed my unrelated problem as well. :D